# Deleting directories with exceptions (in where to find)

Tags: linux, find, rm

I am working with Linux and I am trying to build a script to delete directories (pattern: dir.*) inside /tmp directory.

Inside /tmp directory I have something like this:

```
/tmp/dir.1
/tmp/dir.2
/tmp/dir.3
/tmp/systemd-private-1....
/tmp/systemd-private-2....
```

This is the command that I am running inside the script:

```
find /tmp -type d -name "dir.*" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I am getting some errors because I don't have permission to "look" inside the systemd-private-* directories.

How can I run the mentioned command (inside /tmp) whithout it to run inside the /tmp/systemd-private-* directories (skipping these dirs)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps this works (for 2 different files):

```
find /tmp -type d -name "systemd-private-*" -prune -o -type d -name "dir.*" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
 OR
find /tmp -type d -name "systemd-private-1" -prune -o -type d -name "systemd-private-2" -prune -o -type d -name "dir.*" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Can anyone else confirm as well if this works? Any better solution is appreciated.

Comment: Both should work fine. You can also do `find /tmp -type d \( -name 'systemd-private-*' -prune -o -name 'dir.*' -prune -exec echo rm -rf {} + \)` (drop `echo` if the output looks good) and remove directories in bulks instead of one-by-one.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. Feel free to mark this accepted

Comment: One more thing, is there anyway to run this command only inside /tmp and not inside the folders inside /tmp? This is, only looking for folders inside /tmp directly

Comment: Yeah I think so. Try `echo rm -rf /tmp/dir.*`, is this what you want?

Comment: I was talking about the -maxdepth 1. So it will only look inside /tmp, not recursively.

Comment: find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "dir-*" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: It's the same thing.